# SQL If() On getting the Next date if tomorrows data is null

Tags: sql, date, if-statement

Newbie to SQL Still.

I'm trying to work with a current SQL query I made.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Master.Order Order, Detail.Date
FROM Master INNER JOIN Details ON Master.Order = Detail.Order
WHERE Date = DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())
AND Detail.House = 'MX'
AND (Master.Status <> '\'
AND Master.Status <> 'S' 
AND Master.Status <> '8'
AND Master.Status <> '9')

GROUP BY  Detail.Date, Master.Order
```

My goal Is to have the query pull the next result if tomorrows date has no data.

I'm thinking I need to implement a IF() statement but I'm not really sure how.

Any Suggestions?

Anything Helps.

Thank you,

Sam

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @D-Shih I'm using a program called Idashboards they have custom Queries that use SQL